# Can't change h1 size

Tags: html, css

i can't change size of h1.
i tried %, em, px
i tried also ctrl +f5 to force browser for cashing
but nothing work

i need to know where is the problem and how to keep this text in large size with some words smaller.

this is index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Markvira {% endblock %}
   
{% block content %}

  <!-- main -->
  <main role="main">
    <section class="section-one">
      <div class="container-one">
        <h1 class="h1"> Fly <span>With <br> Our</span> Wings </h1>
        <p class="p">it's the time to fly in yhe world of success with our marketng tools,we give you wings </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section-two">
      <div class="container-two">


      </div>
    </section>



  </main>
  <!-- End of Main -->
{% endblock %}
```

this is style.css

```
@import "header.css";
@import "footer.css";


body html{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 75%;
}

/* section one */
.section-one{
    background-image: url('../images/fly-wings.jpg');
    -webkit-backround-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}


.h1{
    
    font-family: poppins;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.5em 0 1em 15em;
}

.h1 span{
    font-size: 1em;
}

.p{
  font-size: 300px;
  font-family: poppins;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5em 0 1em 12em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    .h1 {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  }
  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .h1 {
      font-size: 100px;
    }
  }

/* End of Section One */

/* Section Two */
.section-two{
  background-image: url('../images/orange-back.jpg');
  -webkit-backround-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

i always get this size and can't increase it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zitfc.jpg)

Comment: Could you produce a code pen or similar reproducable example.

Comment: It should be `h1 { ... }`, not `.h1 { ... }`. You are now targetting `<whatever class="h1">...</whatever>`. Ok, just saw that you also apply the class to the header (which is not really necessary), never mind ...

Comment: @SaschaM78 The h1 tag has a class of `h1` so it should work either way.

Comment: @SaschaM78 While that is true, they do seem to have `<h1 class="h1">`, so it should still be working, despite being an odd way to do it.

Comment: Your code works fine there: https://jsfiddle.net/260d9pa8/ . Below 600px width, the font size changes to 100px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your media queries are completely overwriting where you first define the .h1 class so setting the font size there will not work.

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    .h1 {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  }



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .h1 {
      font-size: 100px;
    }
  }
```

Those two rules are controlling the size of your .h1 class. The max-width one will be anything below 600px and the min-width will be anything above 601px width. Try modifying the font size there. Right now you have it set to 100px for screens that are small in width and 40px for screens that are wider than 600px.

Comment: i tried to remove media at all to see result
but still nothing happen

Comment: Update: when i removed `padding: 1.5em 0 1em 15em;` with your note, everything goes well. do you have and explanation for that?

Comment: You should not use padding to position the text. I would use absolute positioning for the container inside the section to position it where you want it to go like in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshuatuscan/38hktsrj/7/

Comment: Please mark my post as the answer if it's been helpful to you @HatemAbdAlsamad

Comment: Appreciate your time and effort